# PHP script to be displayed by Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, variables

I have a PHP function and I want to return the code below:

```
$myarray = array("one","two","three");
echo "<table><tr>";

foreach($myarray as $array_item)
{
    echo "<td>$array_item</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

So that I can pass the PHP script to Ajax with json datatype.

Is there any way in PHP that I can return these lines of code like a variable so that I can append this "variable" to HTML using jQuery `.html(var)`? Or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myarray = array("one","two","three");
$str = "<table><tr>";

foreach($myarray as $array_item)
{
   $str .= "<td>$array_item</td>";
}
$str .= "</tr></table>";
```

Please echo this variable into the script tag of javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var str1 = <?php echo $str;?>
</script>
```

Pass this str1 variable to your ajax function....

Hope this helps you......

Comment: thanks! this works. Yogesh Suthar's answer works too but without the "echo".

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
$myarray = array("one","two","three");
$str = "<table><tr>";

foreach($myarray as $array_item)
{
    $str.=echo "<td>$array_item</td>";
}
$str.= "</tr></table>";

echo json_encode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://us.php.net/json_encode) Your array. And your jquery can pick it up in ajax response and place in a variable. And in your jquery you can format it in an html table

Answer (score 0):

use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)..it returns the JSON representation of a value

```
 echo json_encode();
```

**OR**

you can use dataType as HTML..(no changes needed on your php script)

```
dataType:'html';
success:function(html){

   jquery.html(html) //apend the returned html to your div 
}
```